# Is this solution of the PDE correct?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, differential

http://www.impa.br/opencms/pt/ensino/downloads/mestrado_profissional_projeto_fim_curso/projetos_fim_cursos_2010/Diogo_Duarte.pdf

Pages 24-25

How do they get from 2.30 to 2.32
using boundary conditions 
$F'(v)=1 \; \text{and} \; f(v)=v^*-I$

Comment: it first finds $A$ from boundary condition 3 mentioned in page 19. parameter $A$ can be written like $$A=((v^*)^{\theta-1}(\theta H+v^*H))^{-1}=\frac{(\theta H+v^*H))^{-1}}{(v^*)^{\theta-1}}$$
and we also know that $V(t)=v$ from two lines bellow 2.18) therefore $V^*=v^*$.
so we can write the second boundary condition (condition 2 from page 19)  like this: $$F(V^*)=A(v^*)^{\theta}H = \frac{(\theta H+v^*H))^{-1}}{(v^*)^{\theta-1}}(v^*)^{\theta}H = v^{*}H/[\theta H +v^*\frac{\partial H}{\partial v}]=v^*-I$$
now just multiply both sides by $[\theta H +v^*\frac{\partial H}{\partial v}]$ and get2.32

Comment: also $A$ is found from boundary condition 3 :$F'(v^*)=1 \Rightarrow \frac{\partial F(v)}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial }{\partial v}(Av^{\theta}H(v))=A\theta v^{\theta-1}H+Av^{\theta}\frac{\partial H}{\partial v}\Rightarrow A(\theta (v^*)^{\theta-1}H+(v^*)^{\theta}\frac{\partial H}{\partial v})=1 \Rightarrow A=(\theta (v^*)^{\theta-1}H+(v^*)^{\theta}\frac{\partial H}{\partial v})^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks alot! But I don't follow the calculations here: $F(V∗)=A(v∗)θH=(θH+v∗H))−1(v∗)θ−1(v∗)θH=v∗H/[θH+v∗∂H∂v]=v∗−I$, How do you get from $(θH+v∗H))−1(v∗)θ−1(v∗)θH$ to $v∗H/[θH+v∗∂H∂v]$

Comment: To make it clear, how do you get: $((θH+v^*H)^-1/((v^*)^(θ-1))$ to $(v^*)H/[θH+(v^*)∂H/∂v]$

Comment: @K.K.McDonald, thanks alot for your help! Is eq. 2.32 correct then? I know he had a mistake in an earlier equation - and the simulations I get from 3.32  are not the samme as his results. So there is something wrong somewhere..

Comment: Caroline I think your equation $F'(V^*)=(\theta H+v^*H)-1(v^*)\theta-1(v^*)\theta H$ is wrong. $(-1)$ is in the power and means the inverse of the matrix and not the subtraction. it's correct form is like the one i wrote in the first comment above. and about mistakes in PDF i didn't see any and i think it's correct but I'm human after all and maybe I'm ignorant to some mistakes in text.